# dockerでcakephp3環境構築時、pluginがcomposeで思った場所にインストールされない

Tags: docker, composer

以下のdockerfileをdocker-compse経由でcakephp3の開発環境を作成しています。

cakephp3のplugin（muffin/trash, ceeram/cakephp-blame）を
`composer require`でインストールしようとしているのですが、
なぜか`/vendor`配下にインストールされてしまいます。

解決方法がわからず、アドバイスいただけないでしょうか？

---

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
volumes:
  mysql.db.volume:
services:
  mysql.db:
    restart: always
    image: mysql:5.7.19
    container_name: mysql.db
    command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - mysql.db.volume:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'hoge_db'
      MYSQL_USER : 'hoge'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'hoge'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      TZ: "Asia/Tokyo"
    ports:
      - '33306:3306'

  cakephp.web:
    container_name: cakephp.web
    build: ./docker-image
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - '8001:80'
      - '2223:22'
    depends_on:
      - mysql.db
    links:
      - mysql.db
```

---

Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:7

#time setting
RUN \cp -fp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Japan /etc/localtime

#prepare
RUN yum install -y unzip

# Add yum repositories. (epel and remi)
RUN rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm && \
    rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-7.rpm
RUN yum install -y epel-release
RUN yum update -y epel-release

#php7 install
#RUN yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php71,epel php php-cli php-common php-devel php-fpm php-gd php-gmp php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysql php-opcache php-pdo php-pear-MDB2-Driver-mysqli php-pecl-memcached php-pecl-msgpack php-pecl-xdebug php-phpunit-PHPUnit php-xml
RUN yum install -y --enablerepo=remi-php71,epel php php-cli php-common php-devel php-fpm php-gd php-gmp php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysql php-opcache php-pdo php-pecl-memcached php-pecl-msgpack php-pecl-xdebug php-phpunit-PHPUnit php-xml

#composer install
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
RUN mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer

#git install
RUN yum install -y git

#cakephp install
RUN cd /var
RUN composer create-project --prefer-dist -n cakephp/app /var/web_app
RUN ln -s /var/phm_app/webroot /var/www/html/phm
#COPY var/cakephp/webroot/.htaccess /var/phm_app/webroot/.htaccess

#plugin install
RUN cd /var/web_app
RUN composer require muffin/trash
RUN composer require ceeram/cakephp-blame

#httpd install
RUN yum install -y httpd
RUN yum install -y httpd-devel
#COPY etc/httpd/conf.d/phm.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/phm.conf

#ssh install
RUN yum install -y openssh-server
RUN passwd -d root
#COPY etc/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config

#service service entry
RUN systemctl enable httpd
RUN systemctl enable sshd

#post processing
VOLUME ["/var/www/html"]
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

Dockerfileの `#plugin install` の部分で、`cd`した先の`/var/web_app/vendor`下にインストールされず、`(ルート)/vendor`配下にインストールされます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DockerfileにおけるRUNはコンテナのレイヤを積み上げる操作になります。
そのため、`/` で開始された場合、`RUN cd /tmp`としても、次に実行するRUNコマンドでの作業ディレクトリは`/`となります。以下が実行結果です。(抜粋)

```
Step 20/26 : RUN pwd
/
Step 21/26 : RUN cd /tmp
Step 22/26 : RUN pwd
/
Step 23/26 : WORKDIR /tmp
Step 24/26 : RUN pwd
/tmp
```

解決するには、上記のように、`WORKDIR`を使用するか、
以下のように記述すると、改善するかと存じます。

```
RUN set -x \
&& cd /var/web_app \
&& composer require muffin/trash \
&& composer require ceeram/cakephp-blame
```

※上記は一例ですので他の箇所も確認してください

参考資料

- [Dockerfile のベストプラクティス #RUN - Docker-docs-ja](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practice.html#run)
- [docker imageを作る際に"cd"できなかった - Qiita](https://qiita.com/gacha-ru/items/2e234b1326d9a38a0bfe)
- [効率的に安全な Dockerfile を作るには - Qiita](https://qiita.com/pottava/items/452bf80e334bc1fee69a)
- [play-with-dockerで検証 - gist - github](https://gist.github.com/okumud/edb89102f18b1dd4d0589d3ba0498bc4)